# Using jqgrid with popover from angular ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqgrid, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a table that I created using jqGrid. I am planning to add a popover functionality, so that when a user click on a cell / grid, then a custom popover is displayed. And I am planning to use the [popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) from angular ui bootstrap.

I have my grid, and I also have my button that can display a pop over. but when I tried to combine both, it doesn't work. I tried to do this with one of my colModel:

```
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                return "<button class='btn btn-primary' popover-placement="top" ng-click='ctrl.handle()'>"+cellvalue+"</button>";
       }
```

I have my controller that include angular pop-over as the dependency, but this doesn't work. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Your double quotes around "top" will cause errors. Either escape them or use single quotes like you used around "ctrl.handle()"

Comment: @brettvd Oops, typo, but I fixed that and it still doesn't work (it doesnt show the angular-ui-boostrap pop over)

Comment: You can use Developer Tools to examine first whether all custom attributes `popover-placement` and `ng-click` are exist by the buttons.

Comment: Do you called `$compile` on the buttons? You can do this inside of `loadComplete` for example.

Comment: @Oleg calling $compile doesn't seem to work.. I saw this post about cellTemplate http://plnkr.co/edit/pucSb6?p=preview is there a similar attribute in jqGrid?

Comment: I'm not angular developer and I have never used popover, but I have some small examples which works and which uses `ng-click`. I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/angular-popover-ng-click.htm) for you. I have to do some other things and I will post my answer with the code later.

Comment: @Oleg hi Oleg, calling $compile for each button works. I had a silly mistake somewhere that makes $compile not working.. Thank you so much! If you can post your comment as solution, I'll accept it as the answer...

Comment: I'll post my answer soon, I still have to do some important things. In my solution the `$compile` will be called **once** after the grid is filled instead of explicitly calling it for every button. So one fills the grid body and then after the body is filled one calls once `$compile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should start with the words that I'm not angular developer and I have never used popover before. So the code which I post below could be not good enough from the angular point of view. Nevertheless it works and it do what you need. Having *working* code you can improve it probably.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/angular-popover-ng-click1.htm) display popover on click on the custom button, which stay opened. Additionally `alert` message will be displayed from the JavaScript function bound using `ng-click`:

[image]

It uses the following HTML markup

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <ng-jq-grid config="config" data="data"></ng-jq-grid>
</body>
```

and the following JavaScript code which contains from three parts. In the first one do the standard thing

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
```

it's important just don't forget to include `"ui.bootstrap"` module required for `popover`.

In the second part one use `myApp.directive` with `$compile` as parameter, which are used for compiling the grid twice: once before placing an empty `<table>` on the HTML page (in `<ng-jq-grid>...</ng-jq-grid>`) and once more inside of `loadComplete`:

```js
myApp.directive("ngJqGrid", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            config: "=",
            data: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var $grid;

            scope.$watch("config", function (newValue) {

                element.children().empty();
                $grid = angular.element("<table></table>");
                element.append($compile($grid)(scope));

                element.append($grid);
                angular.extend(newValue, {
                    autoencode: true,
                    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true }, 
                    autoResizing: { compact: true },
                    autoresizeOnLoad: true,
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        $compile(this)(scope);
                    }
                });

                angular.element($grid)
                    .jqGrid(newValue)
                    .jqGrid("navGrid")
                    .jqGrid("filterToolbar");
            });
            scope.$watch("data", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $grid.jqGrid("clearGridData");
                $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {data: newValue});
                $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I used [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) in the demo, so one don't need to generate and id for the `<table>` element. If you have to use an old version of jqGrid then you should replace the line

```js
$grid = angular.element("<table></table>");
```

to something like

```js
$grid = angular.element("<table id='" + $.jgrid.jqID() + "'></table>");
```

The options `autoResizing` and `autoresizeOnLoad` are specific for free jqGrid and follows setting of the width of the columns based on the width of the data in the column. The options are described in the [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and in the [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column).

In the last part of the code I use `myApp.controller` to initialize `$scope.config` and `$scope.data` with initial data.

```
myApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.config = {
        myClick: function (rowid) {
            alert("Test buton is clicked on rowid=" + rowid);
        },
        colNames: ["Client", "", "Date", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Notes"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "name", align: "center", width: 65, editrules: {required: true},
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["tcn", "tnc", "teq", "tne", "tbw", "tbn", "tew", "ten"] }},
            { name: "myLink", align: "center",
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return "<button class='btn btn-primary' popover-placement='top' popover='" +
                         rowObject.note + "' ng-click='config.myClick(" + options.rowId + ")'>Test</button>";
                }},
            { name: "invdate", width: 125, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" },
                editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
            { name: "closed", width: 70, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
            { name: "ship_via", width: 105, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
            { name: "amount", width: 75, template: "number" },
            { name: "tax", width: 52, template: "number", hidden: true },
            { name: "total", width: 60, template: "number" },
            { name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, edittype: "textarea" }
        ]
    };
    $scope.data = [
        { id: "11",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: 0, tax: 0, closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: 0 },
        { id: "21",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: 351.75, tax: 23.45, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 375.2 },
        { id: "31",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: 400, tax: 30, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 430 },
        { id: "41",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: 200, tax: 10, closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: 210 },
        { id: "51",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: 300, tax: 20, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 320 },
        { id: "61",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: 400, tax: 30, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 430 },
        { id: "71",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: 200, tax: 10, closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: 210 },
        { id: "81",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: 300, tax: 20, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 320 },
        { id: "91",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: 400, tax: 30, closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: 430 },
        { id: "101", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: 500, tax: 30, closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: 530 },
        { id: "111", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note11", amount: 500, tax: 30, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 530 },
        { id: "121", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: 500, tax: 30, closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: 530 }
    ];
});
```

The custom formatter looks like

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<button class='btn btn-primary' popover-placement='top' popover='" +
         rowObject.note + "' ng-click='config.myClick(" +
         options.rowId + ")'>Test</button>";
}
```

I hope that I commented the most important parts of the code.