# Custom HTML colnames in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid table that is working fine. However I want to be able to put a custom `colNames` like:

```
gridOptions.colNames = ["Name", "<b>Period A<b><br>Period B"];
```

I know that for cells, we can do `customFormatter` in every cell just like my question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505360/using-jqgrid-with-popover-from-angular-ui-bootstrap). But is this also supported for `colNames`?

Comment: i think your label is already changed, and you only need to change the row header height..
css on :.ui-jqgrid table.ui-jqgrid-htable

Comment: All depend on **which version of jqGrid you use**. If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then the above code will work even if you will use frozen columns (`setFrozenColumns`) or grouping headers (`setGroupHeaders`) additionally. You can try free jqGrid by changing the URLs of jqGrid to [rawgit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit) URLs.

Comment: @Oleg but using other html elements like for example a checkbox doesn't work in free-jqgrid 4.9.0.

Comment: @low_rents: You should post new answer which describes more clear what you do.