# jqGrid inline delete/edit for local data shows URL not specified

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am pretty new in JQuery and I am developing my first page using jqGrid. I need to fill a grid of some data from a from and in grid I need to delete row one by one and edit row by sending them to the source form and change them next send them back to grid at same row.

the problem is, while the data is local and I don't send any request to server, the delete and edit buttons asks me the URL. my code is as bellow:

```
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid({
datatype: 'local',                        
colNames: [...,'Action'],
colModel: [...,{name: 'act', index: 'act', editable: false, formatter: 'actions',
        formatoptions: {
            keys: true,
            editbutton: true,
            delbutton: true,

            reloadAfterSubmit: false,

            delOptions: {
                onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
                    $(this).delRowData(rowid);
                }
            }
        }
    }],
processing:true,
loadonce: true,
cellsubmit: 'clientArray'
});
```

I want to know is there any option, attribute or any trick to fix this.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use? Do you want to make *local editing* using *inline editing*? Then the value of `editurl` is important and `cellsubmit` will be ignored.

Comment: Its version is more than 5. Because of that much difficulties with working with jquery to implement such a simple logic, I changed everything to Angular and it works perfect.

Comment: There are **two alternative forks** of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, and commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Both have different features now. I try to hold free jqGrid mostly compatible to old versions of jqGrid and thus I hold 4.X.Y version schema. The current version of free jqGrid is 4.13.1, The current version of Guriddo jqGrid JS is 5.10.0. Angular have `directive` feature which allows to use any DOM plugin like jqGrid. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29525862/315935).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set editUrl property to 'clientArray'.