# How to display values in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqgrid

How to display the value of key value pair in jqgrid

my js for grid,

```
 var source = {
    localdata: vm.courseApplications,
    datatype: 'array',
    datafields:
            [
              {
                name: 'course.course_specialization.value',
                type: 'string'
              },
              {
                name: 'subject_category',
                type: 'string'
              },

            ],
    id: '_id'
  };
  $scope.display_rows = vm.courseApplications.length;
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    columns: [
      {
        text: '', sortable: false, filterable: false, editable: false,
        groupable: false, draggable: false, resizable: false,
        datafield: '', columntype: 'number', width: 50,
        cellsrenderer: function (row, column, value) {
          return '<div class="jqxgridmargintop text-center">' + (value + 1) + '</div>';
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Course Specialization',
        datafield: 'course.course_specialization.value',
        groupable: true,
        editable: false,
        cellsrenderer: vm.courseApplicationIdRender
      }, {
        text: 'Subject Category',
        datafield: 'subject_category.value',
        width: '10%',
        groupable: false,
        editable: false
      },
    ],
```

I am not getting any value displayed in grid(empty values are displayed).Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: can u show how your trying to display

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonmap` property in `colModel`. The exact implementation could depend from the `datatype`, which you use in jqGrid, and from the version and the fork of jqGrid. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/vm1b132m/ uses free jqGrid 4.13.5. It uses the following options:

```js
data: mydata.details,
localReader: { id: "_id" },
colModel: [
    { name: "course_specialization", label: "Course", width: 200,
        jsonmap: "course.course_specialization.value" },
    { name: "award", label: "Award", width: 120,
        jsonmap: "course.award.value" },
    { name: "country", label: "Country", width: 100,
        jsonmap: "course.country.value" },
]
```

Comment: Hi oleg,i am getting this error "angular.js:13920 Invalid property: colModel'"

Comment: @nlr_p: Sorry, but the code, which you posted has no relation to jqGrid. [The old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29525862/315935) provides an example of usage Angular 1 with jqGrid, but you want probably use *another* grid.