# InlineEdit with one column auto-complete text field?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am looking for option to support auto-complete type input field on free-jqgrid inline-edit mode. It works great if small 5-10 values into drop-down. I have need to either value need to be searched or needs auto-complete option on the grid.

Let me know if this is possible? if it is please provide some direction or example.

*UPDATE 1*
[Screenshot displays inline input text field needs Auto-Complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uVwI.png)

**UPDATE 2**
I have following order in which files are imported:

```
jquery-ui-min.css
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap-grid.min.css
ui.jqgrid.min.css
font-awesome.min.css
select2.min.css

jquery.min.js
jquery-ui.min.js
select2.min.js
jquery.jqgrid.min.js
tether.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/README.md) to the latest v4.14.0 version of free jqGrid includes the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/, which demonstrates the usage of jQuery UI Autocomplete and select2 with free jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for information

Comment: Hi Oleg, Actually i am looking to support inline input text to support auto-complete. I do not have search field option. Please see UPDATE 1 with screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code like

```js
{ name: "name", align: "justify", width: 80, editrules: { required: true },
    autoResizing: { minColWidth: 80 },
    createColumnIndex: true,
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            initAutocomplete.call(this, elem, "name");
        }
    }, 
    searchoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            initAutocomplete.call(this, elem, "name");
        },
        sopt: [ "cn", "eq", "bw", "ew", "bn", "nc", "en" ],
        clearSearch: true
    } }
```

where `initAutocomplete` function is declared as

```js
var initAutocomplete = function (elem, cmName) {
        $(elem).autocomplete({
            source: $(this).jqGrid("getUniqueValueFromColumnIndex", cmName),
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0
        });
    };
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ugxvr75q/

Comment: Hi Oleg, Something is weird, i have added all the required files but it seems like i am getting Uncaught TypeError: $(…).autocomplete is not a function. Do you see any issues with the order in which i am importing CSS and JS files? see UPDATE2

Comment: @dev.sforce: UPDATE2 don't include any information about versions of JvaScript libraries used. I posted you JSFiddle demo, which you could modify to reproduce the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ugxvr75q/2/, for example, seems to have no problems.

Comment: all versions are correct except bootstrap! i am using Boostrap4

Comment: @dev.sforce: Bootstrap 4 is still in very early development stage (alpha6). Nevertheless free jqGrid 4.14.0 support it. I could not reproduce any problem with Autocomplete. I could see some compatibility problems of select2 with Bootstrap4, but simply CSS settings solves the minor problems. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ugxvr75q/4/

Comment: Thanks for info, i think maybe there something weird on salesforce side, i will update you.

Comment: After arranging exact order of CSS and JS as per your jsfiddle.net worked! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Oleg, does free-jqgrid will work with Reactjs framework?

Comment: @dev.sforce: Yes of cause, you can use it in React Angular and so on. In case of React you need just create new class with 1) `render` method, which create empty table, which you will use for jqGrid 2) `componentDidMount`, where you create jqGrid in the way like you use in JavaScript. It's the standard way used in React. One name it frequently as the "component lifecycle" (see [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)). React like any other frameworks allows to "mount" existing DOM based components like jqGrid.

Comment: @dev.sforce: Angular allows "mounting" of DOM-based components too. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/angular-free-jqGrid.htm) created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42615007/315935) and [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29525862/315935).

Comment: Thank you for the direction, i might have to use Reactjs. Will update.

Comment: @dev.sforce: There are exist *alternatives* to React, which become more and more popular last time. The most interesting are [inferno](https://infernojs.org/), [vue](http://vuejs.org/) and [svelte](https://svelte.technology/), which have **better performance** as React. Someone from there are *compatible to React* (see [inferno-compat](https://github.com/infernojs/inferno/tree/master/packages/inferno-compat)). See [the benchmark](http://stefankrause.net/js-frameworks-benchmark5/webdriver-ts/table.html) (and [here](http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=392)).