# How to utilize jqGrid in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, jqgrid, angular2-directives

In my current project we have been using jqGrid in almost every page. 
We use the grid's full rich featureset including complex grid inline row editing, with drop down, check box and other controls, sorting, column filtering and more.

Now we wish to convert our project into angular 2, but our main problem is replacing jqGrid's rich featureset. Before starting I need to do some POC if all the functionalities can be done in angular 2 based grid.

How can jqGrid be used in Angular 2+?

Answer (score 5):

You don't wrote which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid. The development is spitted after version 4.7. There are now two main forks: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, and commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334).

I find the wrong way to rewrite all existing components on changing of the JavaScript framework, which you use. Every framework modify finally the HTML page via DOM. Every modern JavaScript frameworks support of binding/mounting foreign component, which manipulate DOM internally. It's `directive`/`directives` in Angular 1/2, `componentDidMount` in [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), mounted in [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) and so on. As the result you get Angular 2 components, which have the required functionality. Following the way you can reduce the development time and to use the best components existing on the markt. The end user, which uses your web site will see no difference between native Angular components and the mount JavaScript components.

Another aspect of integration of components in Angular 2 is TypeScript. It's nice language, which provide much better control of datatypes and parameters as JavaScript can. The problem can be solved by providing **`*.d.ts` files** with type definitions for JavaScript components. Free jqGrid 4.14.0 includes [**free-jqgrid.d.ts**](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts), which describes all existing jqGrid options, callbacks and events. Using the corresponding text editor like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) you will get advantage of IntelliSense. As the result you'll improve productivity and quality of the code holding many parts of your existing code.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks a lot for your explanation and suggestions. We are still just exploring to find the best way to make our application responsive and fit with latest java script frameworks e.g. Type script, Angular 2. We use the free jgGrid version. Good to know about the free-jqgrid.d.ts.

Comment: @UtpalKumarDas: Which version of free jqGrid you use? Which CSS framework you use (jQuery UI, Bootstrap or both)? One can easy make jqGrid responsive by adding `$(window).resize` handler which calls `setGridWidth` inside. One can combine the feature with auto-resizing of column width based on the content of the columns, usage of `autoresizeOnLoad: true` and `autoResizing: { compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true }` options `autowidth: true` and other. One can use `labelClasses` with Bootstrap classes like `hidden-xs` to hide columns on low resolution: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/26/

Comment: Hi Oleg, I see the jqGird we used is:- jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid
* Copyright (c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com. We use its free version.

Comment: @UtpalKumarDas: "Free jqGrid", "Guriddo jqGrid JS" are the **names** of the products. You use very old version jqGrid 4.6, which is dead now. I started development of free jqGrid at the end of 2014 after [the changes](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438). You can upgrade to free jqGrid 4.14.0 and use it for free. It's *compatible* to jqGrid 4.6. The performance should be increased additionally and you can use many new features described [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and in READMEs to all published ver

Comment: @UtpalKumarDas: To test free jqGrid you can just change (temporary) 3 lines of your HTML code to load all jqGrid files from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks a lot to let me know about free upgrade version, we will definitely use it.

Comment: @UtpalKumarDas: I forgot to send you the reference to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42615007/315935), which provides [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/angular-free-jqGrid.htm). The demo uses Angular 1, but mounting components in Angular 2 is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think
[ag-grid](http://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php#gsc.tab=0) will be a right choice for Angular2 and React js type of applications, Because they have all the above described features as well as some new exciting features as Floating column ,Grouping column ,pivoting ..bla bla etc.

Comment: Ag-grid doesn't have a built-in string editor, form editor, validator, and much more. The free version of ag-grid has even greater limitations. For example, in terms of working with data on the server side everything is very bad.