# JQgrid with angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, jqgrid, angular2-directives

I have got a situation where i need to integrate free JQgrid with Angular 2 application which is written in TypeScript. I tried to find a simple example written in TS but only got AngularJS examples. There is a another thread [What is the best alternative of jqGrid in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465941/what-is-the-best-alternative-of-jqgrid-in-angular-2) but this does not contain any example.

Can someone please give a simple example step by step.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest [**prime-ng**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) and **ngx-datatable**

Comment: Look at [free-jqgrid.d.ts](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts), which describes options, methods, callbacks and event implemented in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid. Including `free-jqgrid.d.ts` you can access to jqGrid like to TypeScript classes (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/tests/test.ts#L8-L26) the simple demo). If you use  Visual Studio Code then you will get IntelliSense automatically.