# jqgrid in angular2 using free-jqgrid.d.ts

Tags: angular, jqgrid

I refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465941/what-is-the-best-alternative-of-jqgrid-in-angular-2) question on stackoverflow, where the example is given to build the `jqgrid` using angular 1.x version [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/angular-free-jqGrid.htm).

In this answer, I could also see that the  `free-jqgrid.d.ts` is provided, to build
with all existing `jqGrid` options, callbacks and events in angular 2.

Is there any example/steps/guide available to use `free-jqgrid.d.ts` and build the jqgrid?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very busy now and can't create Angular2 demo for you. In general one need just convert AngularJS directive to Angular2 directive. Nothing more. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-component-directives). In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615007/315935) you can find an example of working free jqGrid directive. [Another demo](https://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/angular-free-jqGrid-bootstrap-simplified.htm) shows the usage of free jqGrid directive in Bootstrap. It demonstrates additionally `generateDatalist: true` and `generateValue: true` in `colModel`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! I will try it..

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

angular.json:

```
...     
"styles": [
                  "src/styles.css",
                  "./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css",
                  "./node_modules/free-jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                  "./node_modules/free-jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"
                ]
...
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery:any;
@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
        (<any>jQuery("#grid")).jqGrid({
            colModel: [
                { name: "firstName" },
                { name: "lastName" }
            ],
            data: [
                { id: 10, firstName: "Angela", lastName: "Merkel" },
                { id: 20, firstName: "Vladimir", lastName: "Putin" },
                { id: 30, firstName: "David", lastName: "Cameron" },
                { id: 40, firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
                { id: 50, firstName: "François", lastName: "Hollande" }
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

html:

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```